# how to run c# program in visual studio code in ubuntu

Tags: c#, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I've got a problem with Visual Studio Code in Ubuntu 15.04. When I try to run c# program in Visual Studio Code I get an error "OmniSharp server is not running". How to fix that? I try to run a program by ctrl+shift+p through dnx: Run Command, but I can't. Maybe do I need install something for that?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your problem might be in the OmniSharpServer git page (https://github.com/nosami/OmniSharpServer). You have mono on your system, so you have to clone the OmniSharpServerRepository and execute this lines in a shell:

git clone https://github.com/nosami/OmniSharpServer.git
cd OmniSharpServer
git submodule update --init --recursive
xbuild
If xbuild complained about some assemblies missing something is wrong with the git submodule update --init --recursive. As long as you get the "N Error(s)" message at the bottom you wont find any binary (exe or dll) in the project. If you solve the errors the binaries should be at "OmniSharpServer/OmniSharp/bin/Debug".

A detailed error log would help or a bit more info.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded VSCode + the C# Extension and then installed the .NET SDK from Microsoft's website: https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/linuxubuntu

After I ran my first C# Application I got the prompt listed below on VSCode's Terminal and it worked like a charm! Hope it helps.

Updating C# dependencies...
Platform: linux, x86_64, name=ubuntu, version=16.04

Downloading package 'OmniSharp for Linux (x64)' (23531 KB) .................... Done!
Downloading package '.NET Core Debugger (linux / x64)' (54878 KB) .................... Done!

Installing package 'OmniSharp for Linux (x64)'
Installing package '.NET Core Debugger (linux / x64)'

Finished